# Adobe Analytics Unspecified Values

Tags: adobe-analytics

We have a simple DTM global set to D=g. In our case it is eVar4. This value is not getting set ~30% of the time.

We have another eVar that is set with a direct call. eVar3. This direct call simply sets s.campaign with a data element. This data element returns a value no matter what. (an actual cookie value or a default). Again ~30% unspecified.

I can see referring domain information for these unspecified.

So my question is - If we can collect referring domain information why can't we collect the value for these eVars? Is this cache related or prefetch (prerender)

BTW - webkitVisibilityState -  is used in the 1.5.1 file, so adobe knows about prerender. We are using app measurement 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues to consider here:

- Using Dynamic Variables is a smart idea but DTM doesn't always treat
  them like you'd expect. Given that they are sometimes "flakey" I
  recommend setting your eVars with a data element or JS instead and
  see if that improves your data set.
- If you're using the global variable section of the Adobe Analytics tool remember that those values will execute on a s.t () call. And if you're using a Direct Call Rule after the original PV, the original values may not cascade or be available like you'd expect. One strategy to consider is to use a "global" page load rule instead of the global vars section in the AA tool. And if you set your campaign vars there, a value should be set on every page load.

In summary:

- Populate your vars with data elements or JS vars directly
- Consider moving your AA "Global Variables" to a global page load rule
  for better flexibility and control over timing.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might not have classified your data, To solve this create a classification export file and classify the appropriate columns.

Here are a couple of more suggestions 
https://helpx.adobe.com/analytics/kb/none-unspecified-and-unknown.html